# PayPal Express Checkout Deny pending Order via API

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to deny or accept pending Express Checkout transactions using the API? If so, please advise which API method to use. We process our transactions using setExpressCheckout, getExpressCheckoutDetails, followed by doExpressCheckoutPayment.

Thank you!